# div with screen width and with scroling

Tags: html, css

I would like to create a div that will have the screen width (any screen) and if the content is out of the screen width - I want to display horizontal scroll bar. How can I achieve this?

Comment: You want it to have the size of the screen, but if it's larger than the screen, display a scroll bar? Isn't it the exact size of the screen already?

Comment: @Zirak: At the begining the div doesn't contains data at all so its width is 0. the user may add components to the div so its width grows. I don't want it to grow more then the screen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The scroll will appear in the div if the div content is bigger if you add the next style to the div container:

```
overflow: auto;
```

And if you want to dont display the vertical scroll you need:

```
overflow-y: hidden;
```

Comment: what about the width of the div??

Comment: The div inside of the container can have min-width:100%; for example.
And the container the limitation width.

Comment: I added in my code, how to hide the vertical scroll. Because with auto the scroll will appear when the picture is bigger than the container, vertical bigger or horizontal bigger.

Answer (score 0):

you can use like this....

```
#width1
{
height:200px;
border:1px solid black;
width:100%;
overflow:auto;
}

<div id="width1"></div>
```

Have a look at this fiddle:http://jsfiddle.net/Laqqn/1/

Comment: width:100%; goes out of the screen. In jsfiddle thereis the boundries of the table.

Comment: if you  reduce the width to some other value.the scroll bar comes only for the div...it doesn't goes out off the screen..